# codeigniter 4 select in select query

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

I'm New to CodeIgniter 4 and I want to write this query with CodeIgniter,
How to do that?

```
SELECT student_id FROM student_rel_class WHERE class_id IN (
    SELECT class_id FROM courses WHERE courses.id IN (
    SELECT course_id FROM homework WHERE homework.id = 41
    ));
```

thanks.

this is my CodeIgniter Code

```
$notifications = $stu_rel_class
         ->select('student_rel_class.student_id')
         ->whereIn('student_rel_class.class_id',function (BaseBuilder $builder) use ($data) {
   return $builder->select('courses.class_id')
      ->from('courses')
      ->whereIn('courses.id',function (BaseBuilder $builder) use ($data) {
         return $builder->select('homework.course_id')
             ->from('homework')
             ->where('homework.id',$data['id'])
             ->first();
         });
});
```

Also I can join tables like this

```
$notifications = $stu_rel_class
        ->select('student_rel_class.student_id')
        ->join('courses','student_rel_class.class_id = courses.class_id','inner')
        ->join('homework','homework.course_id = courses.id')
        ->where('homework.id',$data['id'])
        ->findAll();
```

But I not want use join.
can anyone help me?

Comment: This should help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62162063/codeigniters-model-with-querybuilder-join-query/62167868#62167868

Comment: thanks but I not want this @ViLar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this can be found in [Codeigniter Documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html?highlight=getresult)

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();

$query = $db->query("SELECT student_id FROM student_rel_class WHERE class_id IN (SELECT class_id FROM courses WHERE courses.id IN (SELECT course_id FROM homework WHERE homework.id = 41")));

$results = $query->getResultArray();
```

hope this will help solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for your answer, Can I use WhereIn from CodeIginter and not write query like mysql or old php? @me.theblackz

Comment: i don't know if this can help you.

`$builder = $db->table('student_rel_class');`
`$builder->select('student_rel_class.student_id')->whereIn('courses.class_id', 'courses')->whereIn('homework.courses.id', 'homework')->where('homework.id', $data['id']);`

sorry since i don't have enough knowledge, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this won't escape any input that you give it, so if you're passing any kind of user-generated values into this query, you will probably want to escape them with `$db->escape()` or similar. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#escaping-queries

Comment: No it's not work but I thank you for your time @me.theblackz

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand @parttimeturtle